# Read from the specific lines of a csv in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am using pandas to read my csv file as follows.

```
input_data = pd.read_csv( input_file, header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3 )
L= input_data["ingredients"] + '. ' + input_data["recipe"]
documents_list = L.tolist()
```

However. I only wantsto start reading from the 3rd line of my csv file.

For example, if my csv file looks like below, I want my `documents_list` to be:

```
document_list = ['ingredients_3. recipe_3', 'ingredients_4. recipe_4', 'ingredients_5. recipe_5']

id  ingredients     recipe
01  ingredients_1  recipe_1
02  ingredients_2  recipe_2
03  ingredients_3  recipe_3
04  ingredients_4  recipe_4
05  ingredients_5  recipe_5
```

Is it possible to do this in pandas?

Comment: @Vaishali I just notice I marked a lot of dup today :-(

Comment: @Wen, guess all the topics follow that trail once they mature :)

Comment: @Vaishali I will working on a guide line for pandas, for those basic topic :-)